# How do I get the highest "left" value of a group of elements with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, absolute, highest

I need to get the highest `left` value of a set of elements which all have a `left` value as they are set with position absolute. I need to retrieve the element with the **highest left value** so after I can add specific classes to this element.

```
window.load(function()
{
    $('.elements').each(function() 
    {
        var leftValue = $(this).offset().left;
    });
});
```

Comment: A few tweaks : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21855379/1636522.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answers forget one thing: he asks about the **element** of highest left value, not the max value among elements.

So:

```
window.load(function()
{
    var max = 0, $element;
    $('.elements').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).offset().left > max)
        {
            max = $(this).offset().left;
            $element = $(this);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, `$element` will have the element with highest left value

Comment: I tried your code and after I added console.log with both varibles. I do no get the highest value. After I would like to target that element with the highest value. How do you di that?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero: Could you set up a JSFiddle, JSBin, Codepen, Plunkr, or some sort to show what your'e doing?  This code certainly looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could add them to an array and then use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to grab the largest number.

```
var arr = [], max = 0, $elements = $('.elements');

$elements.each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).offset().left);
});

max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

And then use [`$.grep`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to grab the relevant element.

```
var element = $.grep($elements, function (e) {
  return $(e).offset().left === max;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/45QJS/)

Comment: This has an interesting difference from mine that the OP might or might not want.  Mine will choose only a single DIV with the maximum offset, even if there are several with the same value (the first in document order, assuming that's still how jQuery works.)  Yours will choose all that have that maximum value.  I'm not sure which behavior the OP would prefer, but it's an interesting difference to note.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this inside `window.load` or wherever you need it:

```
var max = $('.elements').toArray().reduce(function(max, elem) {
    return Math.max(max, $(elem).offset().left || 0);
}, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

Although you could use `0` in that last line instead of `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, this way you can also account for possible negative values.

Example on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/M763R/)**.

---

### Update

As **[@Eagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902780/eagle)** points out, this, like many answers, missed that the OP wanted the **element**, not the actual **size**.  An updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/hrU45/)** shows a modification of the technique to give that instead.

```
var maxElem = $('.elements').toArray().reduce(function(curr, elem) {
    var left = $(elem).offset().left;
    return left > curr.val ? {elem: elem, val: left} : curr 
}, {elem: null, val: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY}).elem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.load(function(){

        var max = 0;
        $('.elements').each(function() {
            var leftValue = $(this).offset().left;
            if ( leftValue > max ) 
            {
               max = leftValue;
            }
        });

    });
```

The `max` variable is the highest.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `max` built-in function that I'm aware of, but you could

```
window.load(function(){
    var maxLeft = 0;

    $('.elements').each(function() {
        var leftValue = $(this).offset().left;
        if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
            maxLeft = leftValue;
        }
    });

    console.log(maxLeft);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is keep a variable outside of the scope of the `each`. Then you simply compare your value to all the others that you find and assign the highest as you go.

```
window.load(function()
{
    var leftValue = 0;
    $('.elements').each(function() 
    {
        maxLeft = $(this).offset().left;
        if (maxLeft > leftValue) 
        {
            leftValue = maxLeft;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But strangely I'm getting with width of the element, not the left value... what could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Here an alternative using recursivity : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/Y762p/. Notice that you can now resize the demo panel without relaunching the fiddle.

```
var els = $('.elements').get();
var $el = mostLeft(els);

function mostLeft(list) {    
    var biggestLeft; // saves "left" to reduce calls to .offset()
    return function rec(list) {
        var sel, $el, left; // "sel" means "selection"
        if (list.length) {
            $el = $(list[0]);
            left = $el.offset().left;
            sel = rec(list.slice(1));
            if (!sel || left > biggestLeft) {
                biggestLeft = left;
                sel = $el;
            } 
            return sel;
        }
    }(list);    
};
```

Changes comparing to [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21855379/4) :

- the original elements list is not modified anymore, so, it's reusable,
- removed the `sel` parameter to prevent wrong usage and bugs.